# How to show my table horizontally instead of vertically in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a one row output from an SQL Server query. I added it as dataset in SSRS and shown it in a table. The report is given in picture 1. What I want is to show the report vertically as given in picture 2. Normally its very simple (like paste transpose in excel) but it is giving me very tough time in SSRS. Please help.

Current Report

[image]

Expected Report

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create 4 (or 5) detail rows. (depending on whether you want to calculate total or get from the dataset)

For adding new detail row right click on row group cell and click **Insert Row**. Then Click **Inside Group - Below**

[image]

After you have 4 rows you can add the header and data columns to the table.

[image]

Now your data is transposed.

**Bonus:** If you have more than 1 row of data then it will add more rows. But if you do column grouping your table will expand vertically if it has more than 1 row.

[image]